# Solving Trigonometric Equation.

Tags: trigonometry

> Solve for $\theta$ $[0°<\theta<180°]$
>   $$\sin2\theta + \sin4\theta=\cos\theta + \cos3\theta.$$

My solution is here:
$$\sin2\theta + \sin4\theta=\cos\theta + \cos3\theta.$$
After using the transformation formula, I got
$$\sin3\theta\cos\theta=\cos3\theta\cos\theta.$$

I could not proceed from here.

Comment: Use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html correctly in the Right Hand Side

Comment: my big hint: put $\cos \theta=0$ and solve again $\tan3\theta=1$ and solve

Comment: Couldn't you just have $\cos\theta=0$ and $\sin3\theta=\cos3\theta$?  I think that's an easy simplification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Prosthaphaeresis Formulas as suggested,

$$ \sin 2\theta+\sin 4\theta = \cos \theta+\cos 3\theta \\
  2\sin 3\theta \cos \theta = 2\cos 2\theta \cos \theta \\
  \cos \theta \, (\sin 3\theta-\cos 2\theta) = 0 $$

If $\cos \theta=0,\theta=(2n+1)90^\circ$ where $n$ is any integer

We need $0<(2n+1)90^\circ<180^\circ\implies-1<n<1\implies n=0$

Else $\cos 2\theta=\sin 3\theta=\cos(90^\circ-3\theta)$

$2\theta=360^\circ m\pm(90^\circ-3\theta)$

$+\implies\theta=72^\circ m+18^\circ$ and we need $0<72^\circ m+18^\circ<180^\circ\implies m=?$

$-\implies\theta=-360^\circ m+90^\circ$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 5):

\begin{array}{rcl}
  \sin 2\theta+\sin 4\theta &=& \cos \theta+\cos 3\theta \\
  2\sin 3\theta \cos \theta &=& 2\cos 2\theta \cos \theta \\
  \cos \theta \, (\sin 3\theta-\cos 2\theta) &=& 0 \\
  \cos \theta \, (3\sin \theta-4\sin^{3} \theta+2\sin^{2} \theta-1)
  &=& 0 \\
  \cos \theta \, (1-\sin \theta)(4\sin^{2} \theta+2\sin \theta-1) &=& 0 \\
\end{array}

$\therefore \, \cos \theta=0$, $\, \sin \theta=1 \,$, or 
$\displaystyle \, \sin \theta=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{5}}{4}$

$\because \, 0 < \theta < 180^{\circ}$, reject $\, \sin \theta \leq 0$

$\therefore \, \theta = 18^{\circ}$, $90^{\circ}$ (twice) or $\, 162^{\circ}$

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using the [trigometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) you can write

$$\sin 2\theta=2\sin\theta\cos\theta$$
$$\cos2\theta=\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta$$
$$\cos3\theta=\cos^3\theta-\sin^2\theta\cos\theta$$
$$\sin4\theta=4\sin\theta\cos\theta\left(\cos2\theta-\sin^2\theta\right)$$
Then you get
$$2\sin\theta\cos\theta\left(1+2\cos^2\theta-2\sin^2\theta\right)=\cos\theta\left(1+\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta\right)$$
This means $\cos\theta=0$ ($\theta=\pi/2$) is at least one solution.

Answer (score 2):

Using
$$\sin x-\cos x =\sqrt{2} \sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right),$$
given equation can be represented as
$$\cos \theta \sin \left(3\theta - \frac{\pi}{4}\right)=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

It becomes

$$\sin3\theta\, \cos\theta=\cos2\theta\, \cos\theta, $$

First the common factor solution

$$ \cos \theta = 0 \rightarrow \theta = ( 2 n - 1 ) \pi/2 $$

First solution $$ \pi/2$$

Next solve what remains

$$ \sin 3\theta = = \cos 2 \theta = \sin (\pi/2- 2 \theta) $$

$$ 5 \theta = \pi/2 $$

$$ \theta_1 = \pi/10 ,\theta_2 = \pi-\pi/10  = 9 \pi/10. $$